# @JsonIdentityInfo custom reference serialization?

Tags: json, jackson, jsog

With @JsonIdentityInfo we can do things like :

```
 {
    "@id" : 1,
    "value" : 13,
    "next" : {
       "@id" : 2,
       "value" : 42,
       "next" : 1
     }
  }
```

The reference is a primitive type.
It it possible to have the reference be serialized as an object ? example :

```
 {
    "@id" : 1,
    "value" : 13,
    "next" : {
       "@id" : 2,
       "value" : 42,
       "next" : {"$ref":1}
     }
  }
```

**EDIT**

Usefull links

- [An attempt to create a JSOG plugin to handle this (by Jeff Schnitzer)](https://github.com/jsog/jsog-jackson)
- [Discussion on jackson user-list](http://markmail.org/search/?q=JsonIdentityInfo%20list%3Aorg.codehaus.jackson.user#query%3aJsonIdentityInfo%20list%3Aorg.codehaus.jackson.user+page:2+mid%3an6vrh4zi5nm3r3wt+state%3aresults)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "generator" property of the annotation to provide a custom `ObjectIdGenerator` that handles creation and binding of object ids.

However, current implementation does assume that the id is always a scalar type; either JSON String or Number. Support for JSON Objects has been requested, and there is at least one developer working on doing just this (for JSOG notation, similar to what you are trying to do here). You may want to join Jackson dev list to discuss this further.

Comment: Is the requirement that the id is a scalar still true?

Comment: Not completely true any more: special case of a JSON Object with exactly one property is allowed, to support for JSOG.